# Getting "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for..." when working within a messages sticker app

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a custom stickerpack messages app that I've been working on. I'm loading the sticker browser into a programmatically generated view. The stickers are APNGs, not sequences but animated pngs (single files). Everything seems to work but for some reason I get this error when I begin to drag one of them up to a message

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <CKPresentationControllerRootViewController: 0x110a34c20>.
```

I've read that the Unbalanced call issue comes up when a VC is called before it's parent so I moved the generation of the view, createBrowser, into willBecomeActive

Sample code:

```
 func createBrowser() {
    let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .small)
    addChildViewController(controller)
    // This calls a custom constraints function that sets the VC constraints
    view.addSubviewStretched(subview: controller.view)
    controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
    controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self
}


// Get total number of stickers
func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
    return stickers.count
}

func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
    return stickers[index]
}
```

Regardless of where I create the view, either in willTransition or viewDidLoad, the error occurs at random. I'm pushing the app to my iphone 7+ via usb if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your createBrowser function you call **addChildViewController** but you neglected to call

```
controller.willMove(toParentViewController:self)
```

This is required when performing changes to the viewcontroller containment hierarchy and enables UIKit to call viewcontroller transitions correctly

(assuming its being called inside a UIViewController subclass)

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: This isn't working in all cases for me in iMessage, the more I explore the more it seems that the iMessage framework might be doing things a bit differently to usual apps, but most likely good housekeeping in custom code is a good idea in any case.